# View with which role a PostgreSQL setting was changed

Tags: postgresql

Does PostgreSQL record under which user a settings change was carried out?

For example, view if user "postgres" changed the wal_level, or "userA".

If so, how/where can the log be seen?

Comment: Maybe if you log statement = all - but this has serious performance implications. And what the server **cannot** do is audit an edit made to the postgresql.conf file and a restart!

Answer (score 2):

Changing `wal_level` is something that requires a server restart. It can be done in three ways:

1. edit `postgresql.conf` and restart the server
2. change the setting with `ALTER SYSTEM` and restart the server
3. stop the server and restart it with `-c wal_level=whatever`

The first and the third options don't involve an SQL statement or a database user, so they won't leave a trace in the database. You can record calls to `ALTER SYSTEM` by setting `log_statement = 'ddl'`.

So in general, there is no way to find out when and by whom `wal_level` was changed.